# What can you use HTML5's local storage for?

Tags: html, local-storage

I was wondering what are some of the most creative and useful use cases of HTML5's local storage capabilities.

Have you ever encountered any website that uses that feature in a cool way?

In other words, what are some of the examples of places where storing user data in a browser indefinitely can be used?

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: localStorage is good for (1) small/finite amounts of data (2) that doesn't change (3) can be overwritten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one of the most practical reasons to use it is so that the user has some data pre populated when they start their app, i.e. the UI can show data right away, and then sync up with the server behind the scenes.  Combined with an html5 manifest, this is quite powerful juju.

It's also useful for RIAs when the app wants to save data intermittently without going to the server.  For example, an RIA word processor, you can store the document to local storage....

Comment: [For example](http://24ways.org/2010/html5-local-storage), see the 'caching a full interface' section near the end.

Comment: Hi @hvgotcodes can you point to a tutorial on how to provide the user of an app 'prepopulated data' when they start the app, using localstorage ? thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's helpful to store your applications data while the computer is offline. Then you can synchronize the data when the computer is online again.